# Special character dot displacement

Tags: css, fonts

Mysterious problem with Open Sans and ä special character. The dots of Ä are somehow displaced and I can't figure out why.

[image: The dots in Ä character are somehow displaced]

This also happens only in certain text element on certain page. The same font and Ä character works well in other parts of the same page. This also happens only with Firefox and IE.

Comment: Do you have live proof of this? Because http://jsbin.com/dehilacewi/edit?html,output looks perfectly fine in IE and Firefox to me.